# How to add options in ColumnFilterWidgets after initializing the plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following code in a file called **initializing_jquery_datatables.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table').dataTable( {
        "sDom": "<'row'W<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>T",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "bDestroy": false,
        "oColumnFilterWidgets": {
            "sSeparator": "\\s*/+\\s*",
            "aiExclude": [ 0 ]
        }
    ...
});
```

I filter and exclude some columns in another js file like this:

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "oColumnFilterWidgets": {
        "aiExclude": [ 10 ]
    }
});
```

And doesn't work

Comment: Before focusing more on your question please tell me which version of dataTables are you using and if any ajax server sided processing is involved.

Comment: I use datatable 1.9.4 and doesn't involve ajax server side process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it seems that ColumnFilterWidgets does not support changing defaults, like in this [issue](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11888/how-to-set-defaults-for-a-plugin)

Only way I got this running is by totally reinitializing the table.

```
// Code goes here
$(function() {
  oTable = $("#datatable").dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'W<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>T",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "bDestroy": true,
    "oColumnFilterWidgets": {
      "sSeparator": "\\s*/+\\s*",
      "aiExclude": [0]
    }
  })
})

function change(){
  oTable = $("#datatable").dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'W<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>T",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "bDestroy": true,
    "oColumnFilterWidgets": {
      "sSeparator": "\\s*/+\\s*",
      "aiExclude": [2]
    }
  })  
}
```

Note that bDestroy must be true.

[Here's a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/psgVIcTAEj7ThY8wV6NO?p=preview)

Just click the 'click me' button and ignore the lousy layout. Might be related to my updated bootstrap pagination plugin with first/last buttons or some missing css.

Sorry that I can't help you any further:-/